# Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

Sometimes i get this error on **checkout shipping page** with login users (random times):

```
"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"
```

the problem is that rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id is empty when i found the error

> - estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id is empty (response [])
> - No errors on console
> - If a use guest checkout i have no error with same products in cart
> - Json "window.checkoutConfig" country_id and weight are right value
> - Magento 2.2.6 - Developer mode
> - Same error with fixed rate and table rate

How can i debug?

> If i click "Update Shopping Cart" in cart page the problem solved and shipping calculation is right

Comment: I solved this problem quite simply, please check my solution:
https://www.adrianbadowski.pl/2019/03/08/missing-shipping-methods-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disable custom theme
2. Disable one by one custom modules
3. Disable one by one third-party modules

The error was generated by a third-party module. Update this module and error gone away

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." or a "This shipping method is not available" message under the "Shipping methods" section in the checkout, it is because your shipping methods don't have enough information about the customer/order to display any rates. In 99% of the cases, this is because you are using a shipping method that uses for example the customers postcode in order to calculate the shipping costs. Until the customer has entered a zipcode, there is no way for the shipping method to display any prices.

Check this link for more info : http://help.onestepcheckout.com/knowledge_base/topics/shipping-methods

Comment: there is same problem also with fixed rate